# What does angle brackets mean in JS?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, jsx

I see the following example JSX code:

```
const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})<AppBarProps>(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));
```

and I don't understand what  is doing.

So I used babel to translate and get:

```
const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: prop => prop !== 'open'
}) < AppBarProps > (({
  theme,
  open
}) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  })
}));
```

What does this ... `< AppBarProps >` ... mean?  (The rest I  I understand just fine)

Sorry if this seems like the dummest question ever, but can't imagine what is going on here.

Comment: What you actually have is TSX, not JSX. It's typescript.

Answer (score -1):

It's a way to declare [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter in typescript. `styled` returns a HOC that creates a component with the styles attached. I'll breakdown the code to make it more easier to digest:

```
const hoc = styled(MuiComponent)

// StyledMuiComponent now can accept the props with type MuiComponentProps
const StyledMuiComponent = hoc<MuiComponentProps>(styles)
```